# SFTP SSHLibrary Unable to Connect

Tags: robotframework

Im unable to connect to SFTP with below script, any ideas why?

```
*** Variables ***
${HOST} =  mysite.com
${USERNAME} =  username
${PASSWORD} =  password
${PORT} =  22222
${keyfile} =  /Users/victor/.ssh/




*** Test Cases ***
Open Connec
   Open Connection    stage1.globalcashcard.com  alias=LaborReady  port=22222

Enter Credentials
   Login  ${USERNAME}  ${PASSWORD}
List Dir
    List Directory  /


Close ALL Conns
    Close All Connections
```

Side NTOE:
I Even tried it with

```
Login with P. Key
       Login With Public Key  username  /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Results log

```
Status:
FAIL (critical)
Message:
SSHException: SSH session not active
00:00:00.004
KEYWORD SSHLibrary . List Directory /




Documentation:
Returns and logs items in the remote `path`, optionally filtered with `pattern`.
Start / End / Elapsed:
20170607 14:18:33.338 / 20170607 14:18:33.342 / 00:00:00.004
14:18:33.342
FAIL
SSHException: SSH session not active
```

I'm able to login with Filezilla without any issues. On thing I did notice is that I cannot login via terminal with below command

```
ssh username@stg1.mysite.com -p 22222
```

I get prompted to enter password when I enter then I get below message

```
shell request failed on channel 0
```

I able able to connect via Terminal with below command

```
sftp -o "Port 22222" username@stg1.mysite.com
```

Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH and SFTP are different protocols. That is what you validated with your experiences.

When you use SSHLibrary you can use similar functions you get in SFTP, but not the exact commands.

Comment: Thanks. I found that our sftp server blocks ssh.